# dynamic drop down using select tag and ajax on onselect event

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am developing an web application. I have one drop down list of category. On select event, the category is sent to server and data is fetched in the JSON format of subcategory belonging to that category. Depending on that, I have created dynamic drop down select list. But the problem is, When I select the category in drop down1, then all the subcategories belonging to that category goes in the single row of drop down(single option tag)

my ajax code for drop down on success

```
 success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data,function(index, store)  {
                console.log(store);
            $.each(store, function(key,value){
                     if(key === "subcatname"){
                       options.append($("<option  />").val(value).text(value));
                        };
                   });
              });     
      },
```

I am getting output like [image]

It should  be like

```
Select Subcategory

TO Increase RAM

To change Moniter

To change mouse
```

like one below another.

my HTML code is

```
 <select id="dynamic_select_delete" style="height: 30px;">
                <option id="options">Select Subcategory </option>
            </select>
```

What I am missing in ajax?
Thanks

Comment: where is the variable `options` defined? Is it the select object or its option object?

Comment: "options" is id of the first option tag whose value id "select Subcategory" declared in select tag already. updated the code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the info you gave in comment this should be the right way

```
options.parent().append($("<option  />").val(value).text(value));
```

Or

```
$("<option  />").val(value).text(value).insertAfter(options);
```

Right now you are appending to the `option`(child of `select`) but you should be appending to the `select` element, its parent.

Comment: Thanks, But one more thing when I change the drop down from category like Hardware to software, the options from subcategory remain their and software subcategory options add appended to it. How should I clean first subcategory options

Comment: Do this before appending subcategories `$("#dynamic_select_delete").find("option").not("#options").remove()`

Comment: by adding this statement, contents of subcategory gets changed, But I can see only the last option in child drop down like "To change mouse" in hardware category. I want all options from Hardware

Comment: add this statement before the loop not in the loop

Comment: yes, I got as expected, adding before loop, Thank you so much